# GUI not rendering <br> and new line showing error messages

Tags: web8.5, gui-extensions, event-system, extension-errors

Recently I received client requirements for validation Component fields using Event System. I am facing issue in message with multiple lines.

```
throw new Exception(“Experience must <br> be greater <br> than 10”);
```

The `<br>` tag is not working in the Tridion GUI message.

**looking for solutions and ideas.**

[image]

Answer (score 9):

You would have to make CSS updates through a GUI extension besides using the new line (\n) in your exception message.

- In your event system exception, you will be using the new line like this:

  `throw new Exception("Some text before new line.\nSome text after new line.");`
- In the GUI extension, set the CSS `white-space` property to `pre-wrap` in the div element of the notification message.

  `white-space: pre-wrap;`

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Assuming it's C# .NET, you can try using the `Environment.NewLine` property from the `System` namespace. NewLine actually equals \r\n.

```
String.Format("NewLine: {0}  first line{0}  second line{0}  third line",
                          Environment.NewLine);
```

Comment: I tried and not worked.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try xhtml line break

`<br/>`?

Comment: I tried and not worked <br/> tag.